Get a list of available `-LogName` and `-Source` for `Write-EventLog` without the administrator privilege
Background

I want to write error messages to the Windows Event Log in a PowerShell script with Write-EventLog.
I don't have administrator privilege in the runtime environment, so I can't run New-EventLog for the script to create a customized LogName.
When you specify -LogName or -Source that are not available from the script, you will get an exception like this:

PS C:\> try { Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source 'NewApplication' -EventId "400" -Message "TEST MESSAGE" } catch { $_ | Format-List * -Force | Out-String }


PSMessageDetails      :
Exception             : System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
                           at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.FindSourceRegistration(String source, String machineName, Boolean readOnly, Boolean wantToCreate)
                           at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(String source, String machineName, Boolean wantToCreate)
                           at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteEventLogCommand.BeginProcessing()
                           at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing()
                           at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin()
                        The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
                        MyComputer
TargetObject          :
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-EventLog], SecurityException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.SecurityException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteEventLogCommand
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}

Problem
So I want to get lists of available -LogName and -Source for the script.
You can get a list of events with Get-EventLog -List or Get-EventLog -LogName <LogName>, but it contains -LogName and -Source that are unavailable for my script. It also contains only the events that are already logged to Event Log (it is not an exhaustive list of available -LogName and -Source).
Question
Is there any way to get the exhaustive list of available -LogName and -Source for Write-EventLog without the administrator privilege?
Edit
For example, you will get the following error when you specify unmatched -LogName and -Source:
PS C:\> Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "Application Popup" -EventId "1000" -Message "TEST MESSAGE"
Write-EventLog : The source 'Application Popup' is not registered in log 'Application'. (It is registered in log 'System'.) " The Source and Log properties must be matched, or you may set Log to the empty string, and it will automatically be matched to the Source property.
At line:1 char:1
+ Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "Application Popup" -Ev ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-EventLog], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The source 'Application Popup' is not registered in log 'Application'. (It is registered in log 'System'.) " The Source and Log properties must be matched, or you may set Log to the empty string, and it will automatically be matched to the Source property.,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteEventLogCommand

But when you set an empty string to -LogName according to the error above, you will get another error like this:
PS C:\> Write-EventLog -LogName "" -Source "Application Popup" -EventId "1000" -Message "TEST MESSAGE"
Write-EventLog : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'LogName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:25
+ Write-EventLog -LogName "" -Source "Application Popup" -EventId "1000 ...
+                         ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Write-EventLog], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteEventLogCommand


The answer is most likely no.


You can get the list of log names that Get-EventLog can target as follows:
$logNames = 
  (Get-EventLog -LogName *).Log

Source names can be discovered via the registry, on a per-log basis:
# Initialize an ordered hashtable that will contain log names as keys 
# and the corresponding source names as the values.
$sourcesPerLog =  [ordered] @{}

# Loop over all log names and find the names of all sources registered
# for that log.
# Exclude the 'Security' log, because its sources cannot be queried without
# elevation; however, given that this log is "for system use only", that shouldn't be a problem.
Get-EventLog -LogName * | 
  Where-Object Log -ne Security | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $logName = $_.Log
    $sourcesPerLog[$logName] = 
      (Get-ChildItem HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\$logName).PSChildName
  }

# Output for diagnostic purposes.
$sourcesPerLog

Sample output:
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Application                    {.NET Runtime, .NET Runtime Optimization Service, Application, Application Error...}
HardwareEvents
Internet Explorer
Key Management Service         KmsRequests
OAlerts                        Microsoft Office 16 Alerts
System                         {ACPI, AFD, Application Management Group Policy, Application Popup...}
Windows PowerShell             PowerShell

Note:

To get the array of sources registered for the Application log, for instance,  use $sourcesPerLog['Application'] or $sourcesPerLog.Application.

Note that the Security log is deliberately skipped, as its sources cannot be queried unless you're running with elevation (as administrator).

However, given that this log is "for system use only" and therefore shouldn't be written to by user code, this isn't much of a limitation.




Caveat:

Get-EventLog is based on deprecated Windows APIs, and that the recommendation is to use Get-WinEvent instead; from the Get-EventLog help topic:


Get-EventLog uses a Win32 API that is deprecated. The results may not be accurate. Use the Get-WinEvent cmdlet instead.


Notably, additional event logs may exist that Get-EventLog cannot query.

