System.Diagnostics.EventLog#WriteEvent() can't find a specific event ID
Background
As described in this question, I am trying to use System.Diagnostics.EventLog#WriteEvent() as an alternative for New-WinEvent and Write-EventLog cmdlet.
Problem
I tried to write the following log with WriteEvent():

LogName: Application
Source: Application Error
Event ID: 1005

$eventLog = [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::new('Application')
$eventLog.Source = 'Application Error'
$eventLog.WriteEvent(
  [System.Diagnostics.EventInstance]::new(1005, 0, [System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType]::Error),
    @(
      'FilePath.exe',                            # FilePath
      'Application Name',                        # AppName
      0x1234,                                    # StatusCode
      1                                          # MediumType
    )
  )

But in Event Viewer, I got the following message:
The description for Event ID 1005 from source Application Error cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

FilePath.exe
Application Name
4660
1

The message resource is present but the message was not found in the message table

On the other hand, when I used the New-WinEvent cmdlet, I got the following message (this is what I expected).
New-WinEvent -ProviderName "Application Error" -Id 1005 -Payload @(
  'FilePath.exe',                            # FilePath
  'Application Name',                        # AppName
  0x1234,                                    # StatusCode
  1                                          # MediumType
)

Windows cannot access the file FilePath.exe for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program Application Name because of this error.

Program: Application Name
File: FilePath.exe

The error value is listed in the Additional Data section.
User Action
1. Open the file again. This situation might be a temporary problem that corrects itself when the program runs again.
2. If the file still cannot be accessed and
    - It is on the network, your network administrator should verify that there is not a problem with the network and that the server can be contacted.
    - It is on a removable disk, for example, a floppy disk or CD-ROM, verify that the disk is fully inserted into the computer.
3. Check and repair the file system by running CHKDSK. To run CHKDSK, click Start, click Run, type CMD, and then click OK. At the command prompt, type CHKDSK /F, and then press ENTER.
4. If the problem persists, restore the file from a backup copy.
5. Determine whether other files on the same disk can be opened. If not, the disk might be damaged. If it is a hard disk, contact your administrator or computer hardware vendor for further assistance.

Additional Data
Error value: 0x1234
Disk type: 0x1

I tried with other event sources and IDs, and got the following result:



Method/Cmdlet
Source
Event ID
Result




WriteEvent()
Application Error
1000
✔


WriteEvent()
Application Error
1005
Message becomes "The description ... cannot be found"


WriteEvent()
Application-Addon-Event-Provider
1
✔


New-WinEvent
Application Error
1000
No error but can't set %2, %3, ... in the message


New-WinEvent
Application Error
1005
✔


New-WinEvent
Application-Addon-Event-Provider
1
✔


Write-EventLog
Application Error
1000
No error but can't set %2, %3, ... in the message


Write-EventLog
Application Error
1005
Message becomes "The description ... cannot be found"


Write-EventLog
Application-Addon-Event-Provider
1
No error but can't set %2, %3, ... in the message



Question
I don't want to use different methods/cmdlets based on the event source/ID. I want to write event logs in a unified way.
Why does WriteEvent() for event ID 1005 cause the message The description for Event ID 1005 from source Application Error cannot be found.?
Edit
Same as  this question, I don't have administrator privilege in the runtime environment, so I can't run New-EventLog to create a customized LogName.

What's the motivation behind reusing an existing/built-in message template? Will you not have access to create/register new log sources on the target systems?

Instead of using built-in sources like "Application Error", it's recommended to create a custom event source specifically for your app since "Application Error" is technically a system owned source. New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source MyAppErrors

I edited the question. I don't have administrator privilege in the runtime environment, same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/79239902/3902663 .
